# How to apply standardization for train set inside gridsearchcv?

Tags: python, cross-validation, gridsearchcv, standardization

It is a question more about theory than a problem in code itself. I have the following Pipeline, which will then be used in a GridSearchCV:

```
my_model = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('model', model())])

cv = GridSearchCV(my_model , parameters, cv=5).fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Then, I will use the trained cv with the best hyperparameters to predict on the test set:

```
cv.predict(X_test)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Will GridSearchCV automatically apply the scaler only to the training set for each fold? That is, follow this logic for each fold:

> scaler fit and transform on the train_set_fold (using, of course, the
> data only for the training set in question) **->** train the model **->**
> apply scaler transform on the test_set_fold

2. When calling cv.predict, will GridSearchCV automatically apply the scaler.transform (learned previously on one of the folds with just the training set) to the set X_test before making the prediction itself?